# apt-mirror: can't create /dir:/mirror directory at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 342

Tags: apt, repository, apt-mirror

The title of this question is the error message I receive after installing apt-mirror and apache2. As per the instructions set out by all the guides I've encountered. It informs me to modify `/etc/apt/mirror.list` with a directory that I've created for the repository to end up.

ie set `base_path /dir`

I've added the repos I want in my list as well. Once I've entered the following

```
$ sudo apt-mirror
```

It returns with the error in the title

```
apt-mirror: can't create /srv/local-repo:/mirror directory at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 342
```

I investigated that file:line, and I'm too amateur to decipher the issue.

Answer (score 1):

apt-mirror is meant to be run by the user **apt-mirror**, not **root**.

So don't run it as **root**. It will mess everything up.

First, make sure that the path is owned, readable and writable by the **apt-mirror** user.

And launch it as that user:

```
sudo -iu apt-mirror apt-mirror
```